Permission to use Rick Riordan characters
I am already working on a novel with Rick Riordans characters and was wondering if I could get permission to use them from his copy right holders before l proceed with book 2 that has THE KANES introduced.
Hope you understand.

This is about the sixth different question from someone asking if they can use details from Rick Riordan's novels in their own writing.

Here are all the questions relating to Rick Riordan.

Took only typing Rick Riordan fanfiction into Google to find this:

Do you ever read fan fiction?
No, never. I am aware of fanfic, but I go out of my way to avoid it. For one thing, it's legally tricky
ground. I can't actively endorse anyone else using my copyrighted
material. I also don't want anyone claiming later on, "Hey, you got
that idea from my fan fiction!"Aside from that, I have to admit I find
fan fiction a little unsettling. It's like somebody getting into my
closet and trying on my clothes. It's just weird seeing someone else
try to write about my characters. Then again, I can't listen to the
audio versions of my books. It drives me crazy hearing another voice
beside my own narrating my stories. And, as I've explained many times,
I also couldn't watch the Percy Jackson movie for much the same
reason.

and

I love the series so much I'd like to continue writing the books myself. Can I have permission to use your characters and ideas?
I’m honored you like the series so much, and I get this question
frequently, but my publisher would be pretty upset if I gave anyone
else permission to write about Percy's world. If you’re writing
stories just for your own amusement and not planning to publish or
share them, that’s no big deal. But if you are hoping to write a book
that would be published some day, you need to come up with your own
characters, settings, and stories. Of course, Greek mythology itself
is thousands of years old. Anyone can write about the gods and
monsters. Perhaps you can come up with your own original spin on that
material.

So it really doesn't seem likely you'd get that permission to write and officially publish your work. Hobby, noncommercial fanfiction seems to be tolerated though.

"Hobby, noncommercial fanfiction seems to be tolerated though." I don't know how you come to that conclusion. Riordan clearly says in your quote: "If you’re ... not planning to publish or share them, that’s no big deal." His criterion is not publishing the fanfiction. He doesn't make an exception for non-commercial publications.

@Ben I don't think by "publish" he means "post on an internet archive". You're not "hoping to write a book that would be published" if you plan to just post it online. There's no "please don't do this" request of the fans, no "I wish it didn't exist" lament, and certainly no threat of any legal action against fanfic archives. Just an "I can't actively tell you yes" and "personally, I'm not fond of the idea". In summary, it isn't welcome, but it is tolerated.

Legally, publishing is making something available to another person or to the general public. The channel doesn't matter. If I print a copy of what I wrote and give it to a friend, legally that is publishing. If OP posts fanfiction to an internet forum where others can read it, legally that is publishing. I think Riordan means by publishing what it legally meants. Also, he said "publish or share". So even if you assume Riordan understands publishing as only printed books, he clearly means other means of sharing fanfiction as well.

@Divizna posting something online is publishing, period. That is already legally decided. Whether it is sold or not, you have published it.
As the author is quoted in the post: "If you are writing stories just for your own amusement and not planning to publish or share them, that's no big deal."
The moment you share them, in any way, that is publication and a violation of trademarks and copyrights and opens you up to lawsuits. Especially if the sharing is easily proven by being posted on the Internet somewhere.

I don't know what you want from us then. Contact the copyright holders of Riordan's works and inquire with them. We cannot answer for them.
